# List all variables from embeded object

Tags: javascript, embed

Say I have an object with an embedded flash file.

```
<object>
    <embed src="something.swf">
</object>
```

I can get a specific variable from it using `window.document.embeds[0].GetVariable("foo")`. What I want to do is get a list of all the valid variables from that embedded object. I know that I can type `window` in the Javascript Console to see a tree of all variables, however it does not list the variables for embedded objects.

Is there an equivalent 'command' to do the same thing but list all embed variables?